# CPtrArray without MFC (to STL or Boost)

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm trying to leave MFC, how can I **replace CPtrArray** ?

maybe I can **typedef** it to something alike `vector<void *>`

What is better way to save full functional of this class ?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to write it yourself, you can use [`boost::ptr_array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html) instead. It uses an underlying `std::vector<void*>` to store the pointers.

Answer (score 4):

You should not have been using CPtrArray in the first place. It is a dangerous old class from the dark days before Visual C++ supported templates and can only be used with enormous caution. Its problem is that it stores pointers (any pointer!) as `void*` and that means that when you get the pointer back out of the array you have **no type information whatsoever**. If your code relies heavily on this you have been at risk of misusing objects and of serious memory leaks (e.g. failing to call destructors).

`boost::ptr_array` is not a direct replacement for `CPtrArray`, it is a properly templated type-sensitive class: its nearest MFC equivalent would be `CArray<T>`. The fact that it uses `void*` to handle the pointers is (essentially) an implementation detail, and not the same at all as using `vector<void*>` directly.

(If you are aware of all the issues with `CPtrArray` then I apologise for preaching to the choir, but I thought any question about `CPtrArray` needed a warning note attached.)